# Testing values from other services in Angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm using Karma and Jasmine to write unit tests for an AngularJS application and I'm having some trouble verifying data in one of my tests. In this test I have a component controller which makes use of a service. In my test I'm calling a method which sets a value inside that service. When I test to see if it has been set correct it looks like it has not. Have I set-up my test correctly to be able to check this?

**Component with service**

```
angular.module('myApp').component('actions',{
templateUrl: '/app/components/actions/actions-template.html',
controller: ['action.service', '$location', function (actionService, $location) {
    var self = this;

    self.setActiveItem = function (item) {
        actionService.activeItem = item;
    };        
}]});
```

**My test**

```
describe('action.component.tests', function () {
var actionListComponent;
var actionServiceTest;

beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, $componentController) {
    actionListComponent = $componentController('actions');
    actionServiceTest = $injector.get('action.service');
}));

describe('action.component method tests', function () {
    it('Should set an active item in the action service', function () {
        var item = {};
        actionListComponent.setActiveItem(item);
        expect(actionServiceTest.activeItem).toBe(item);
    });
});});
```

The error message I get back is that the test failed because the `item` I used for the test doesn't match what is currently set in `actionServiceTest.activeItem`. I can confirm using console logging that no matter what I use for my item in the test it doesn't appear to set it inside `actionServiceTest.activeItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be looking at the service call you're making. You are setting it directly, as though it were an object, but shouldn't it be a method?

```
Service:
function activeItem(item) {
  this.activeItem = item;
}
```

Your call from your controller would be:

```
actionServiceTest.activeItem(item);
```

Then your test should be:

```
describe('action.component method tests', function () {
  it('Should set an active item in the action service', function () {
    spyOn(actionServiceTest, 'activeItem').and.callThrough();
    var item = {};
    actionListComponent.setActiveItem(item);
    expect(actionServiceTest.activeItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith(item);
  });
});
```

See if that does it for you.

You're testing that the method on the service gets called, and that it sets something, by looking at what the method is called with. If you want to test the logic inside the service, then write a separate unit test for the service, it shouldn't be here though.